# How can I identify IP address time to renewal in C program?

Tags: c, linux, ip-address, dhcp

I know how to get IP address of the interfaces using `getifaddrs()`. But how to know how much time is left until this address may change due to DHCP lease expiration? `dhcpclient` shows it when renewing IP address, but is it possible to know this value (actually remaining time) in the C program?

Comment: `getifaddrs` is just a simple abstraction on top of DNS and the host resolver.  What are you really trying to do? (that is, what do you need to know the renewal time of a particular IP address?  The local host's IP address renewal time or a remote hosts's IP address renewal time?

Comment: Local host renewal time. The device will not have assigned fixed IP address, and I want to know how much time left for remote device to connect to this device using present IP address.

Comment: I would go to the [source](https://github.com/isc-projects/dhcp/blob/master/client/dhclient.c) and try to figure it out from there. That's actually the source for `dhclient` but you should be able to find the source for `dhcpclient` too.